# Vue.js aplying phone number format

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and was trying to find a way how to format a phone number in an input field to the desired format. I was able to find an answer here on stackoverflow written in plain javascript but I dont know how to use the regex in Vue.

Solution in javascript

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

So my question is how to apply it on this input div? So it allows the user to type only numbers and as he is typing the number is showing in the desired format.

```
<div contentEditable="true" class="inputDiv"></div>
```

Example what I would like to achive using vue.js.

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/>
```

I was trying to look for an answer which is probably pretty stright forward but since I'm new to Vue I was unable to find anything which would help me to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you want: you want to apply some format to the input value before sending it to your back-end? Do you want to validate wether the number complies with a specific format? Do you want to modify the input so when the user writes with bad format the application corrects it in real time?

Comment: sorry for the questing being confusing. I edited the question. Hope it is providing all the needed info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably need to have a look at how vue works and have some walk through to get a better understanding.

Their documentation is awesome, you can start from there - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

For the question, here is a way you can utilise the framework

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  methods: {
    acceptNumber() {
        var x = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  this.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Phone number</h2>
   <input v-model="value" type="text" @input="acceptNumber">
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for and you are right some walk through would likely be needed. Thank you!

Comment: Just one more question I'm having problem to attach it to div <div contentEditable="true"> instead of input... what would I need to do differently?

Comment: `v-model` works on `value` attribute of the element - and on div `v-model` doesn't works. Look for `v-bind` to make it more editable

Comment: @SatyamPathak, can you have a look at a vee-validate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444033/vue-js-bootstrapvue-veevalidate-cannot-validate-datepicker ?

Answer (score 2):

Introducing [**Vue-The-Mask**](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask).

`npm install vue-the-mask`

**In your component**

```
<template>
    <input v-mask="['(###) ###-####']"/>
</template>

<script>
import {mask} from 'vue-the-mask'
export default{
    name: "myComponent",
    directives:{mask}
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, so many uses

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Vue you handle forms with [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html). In a typical form, you would have maybe a `phoneNumber` variable in your component and would bind it to the input with `v-model`:

```
<template>
  <input name="phone" v-model="phoneNumber" />
</template>

<script>
export default new Vue ({
  data() {
    return {
      phoneNumber: '',
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

The problem is that `v-model` does not allow you to change the value dynamically as the user types, so that doesn't work for you.

Instead of binding with `v-model`, however, you can still provide the value with `v-bind` and react to user input with `v-on`.  The following snippet would always transform whatever the user writes to mayus:

```
<template>
  <input name="phone" :value="phoneNumber" @input="handleUserInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default new Vue ({
  data() {
    return {
      phoneNumber: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUserInput(input) {
      this.value = input.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Applying format to the phone number is just a bit more complicated that `toUpperCase()`, but the idea is the same:

```
<template>
  <input name="phone" :value="phoneNumber" @input="handleUserInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default new Vue ({
  data() {
    return {
      phoneNumber: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleUserInput(input) {
      var replacedInput = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      this.value = !replacedInput[2] ? replacedInput[1] : '(' + replacedInput[1] + ') ' + replacedInput[2] + (replacedInput[3] ? '-' + replacedInput[3] : '');
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My 5 cents. Imagine you have a phone model, that you wish to apply the formatting to.

```
 data() {
   return {
     phone_number: null,
   };
 }
```

Your template would look something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="tel"
      placeholder="(123) 456-7890"
      class="form-control"
      id="input-phone"
      v-model="phone_number"
      maxlength="16"
      @input="enforcePhoneFormat()"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

So, on input, you call the enforcePhoneFormat() method, which uses regex and transforms the input, to a following format - `(123) 345-6789`.

```
methods: {    
  enforcePhoneFormat() {
    let x = this.phone_number
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);

    this.phone_number = !x[2]
      ? x[1]
      : "(" + x[1] + ") " + x[2] + (x[3] ? "-" + x[3] : "");
  }
}
```

To change the preferred format, you would have to change the regex, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some of the open source Vue components for telephone input like:

https://github.com/LouisMazel/vue-phone-number-input

or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input

They are really easy to use and and it will save you a lot as you would waste making your own phone input component.

Comment: That does not help me unfortunately. I'm actually not going after formatting a phone number but using it as an easy to understand example instead of lengthy describing the very specific case I have.

Comment: How can I get the formated number ( country code + phone number) using the component from the first link you provided ?

Comment: Install it with npm, include it as it is shown in usage and just use it like :
<VuePhoneNumberInput v-model="yourValue" />
Also you have listed properties which you can use on this component in order to customize it. @IstiaqueAhmed

Comment: @N.Djokic, how can I set country code and phone number l programmatically with `JS` for the component in 1st link ?

Comment: @N.Djokic, can you have a look at a vee-validate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444033/vue-js-bootstrapvue-veevalidate-cannot-validate-datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to @Satyam Pathak code, to support dynamically passing in property names.

```
<script>
export default new Vue ({
  data() {
    return {
      objectName: {},
    }
  }
})
</script>

methods:{
formatPhoneNumber(propertyName) {
      var x = this.objectName[propertyName]
                  .replace(/\D/g, "")
                  .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);

      this.objectName[propertyName] = !x[2]
        ? x[1] : "(" + x[1] + ") " + x[2] + (x[3] ? "-" + x[3] : "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let phone_format = function (number) {
    var x = number.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
    if (number.length < 11) {
        number = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3]:'');
    }
    return number;
};
```

You can use above fnc.

I use like that.

```
<div class="position-relative">
    <input v-model="aa" style="opacity:0" />
    <div v-html="phone_format(aa)" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;pointer-events: none;"></div>
</div>
```